# substitute strings with special characters in a huge file using sed

Tags: string, bash, sed, special-characters

I'm stuck in this very easy problem (I hope it is for you).
I need to substitute several strings with special characters in a huge file.
I'm trying using sed and bash because I'm a linux user but I've only used sed for "standard" string so far.

These are the kind of strings that I'm trying to manipulate

`(alpha[1],alpha[2])` and `diff(A45(i,j),alpha[1])`

and the substituting strings would be

`(i,j)` and `dzA45(i,j)`

I tried `sed -i 's/(alpha[1],alpha[2])/(i,j)/g' $filetowork` and 
`sed -i 's/\(alpha\[1\],alpha\[2\]\)/i,j/g' $filetowork` without any success

The second option seems to work for the first kind of string but it doesn't for the second one, why?

could you please help me? I took a look around stackoverflow old questions without any help, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried on the command line, but

```
echo "(alpha[1],alpha[2])" | sed 's/(alpha\[1\],alpha\[2\])/(i,j)/
```

worked for the first case. Please note that you should not escape `(` or `)`, because that is how you activate groups.

For the second one

```
echo "diff(A45(i,j),alpha[1])" | sed 's/diff(A45(i,j),alpha\[1\])/dzA45(i,j)/'
```

worked for me. The same case, don't escape brackets!

Comment: thank you so much! Now I'll for the strings that I have to substitute and I'll let you know!

Comment: I just want to add that I needed to substitute some special characters like `$` and I used brackets for them like `[$]`

Comment: How about using parenthesis or brackets in sed output?

Comment: If I wanted to substitute a string `abc` to `(abc)`? I've seen that it is possible but only in a simply way I mean only groups of numbers and letters not a mix of them

Comment: You can substitute whatever you want for whatever you want, as long as it's describable by regular expressions... You can mix numbers, letters, anything, just do something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` or similar. Anyway, there are tons of tutorials out there...